# Query a nested HTML tag to return the value of it's attribute in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

What is the best way to have PHP query a div with class `active` and then query a div inside of that with class `content` that has an attribute `song` and have it return that value as a string?

I currently have some code that looks like this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$resulted = $xpath->query('div[@class="active"]');
$active= $resulted->item->query('div[@class="content"]');
```

but it's been running errors:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object`

My javascript generated HTML:

```
<div class="item active" style="display: block; left: 685.5753504672897px; top: 0px; height: 475.3125px; width: 318.84929906542055px; font-size: 100%; z-index: 32768; visibility: visible;">
<canvas class="content landscape" href="#" src="imgs/dead.jpg" title="The Dead Weather - Horehound" id="3" num="0" song="Horehound" origproportion="1.0062305295950156" width="323" height="482"></canvas></div>
```

I feel like this isn't the right way to go about this, but since I am new I am not sure, and from what I've seen there are many ways. I'm just looking for the best/simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you have to do like

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$resulted = $xpath->query('div[@class="active"]');
foreach($resulted as $result){
$active= $result->item->query('div[@class="content"]');
}
```

If its not what you wanted to do. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just knocked this out:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$resulted = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"active")]/*[contains(@class,"content")]');

echo 'Found items: ' , $resulted->length , "\n";

foreach ($resulted as $result) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

I've popped it into: http://3v4l.org/sug3m

Only thing I didn't understand was your comment on Javascript?  How are you feeding your JS generated content back to PHP?